# Django Object Value Pull Resulting in Tuple?

Tags: python, django

New to Django and trying to understand a mysql query that I currently have working somewhat. It is pulling my database values but it is print this off as an array or tuple? I'm not sure exactly which one, I am assuming there is some .value like DFs but using `object.value` I thought would have done this? Seems so easy but after a few hours I need a nudge please.

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import PreviousLossesMlbV2


def show_view(request):
    games = PreviousLossesMlbV2.objects.values('actual_over_under_result_field')
    results = PreviousLossesMlbV2.objects.values('actual_over_under_result_field')
    return render(request,"show.html", {'games': games, 'results': results})
```

**show.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Django CRUD Operations</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          {% for game in games %}
        <p>{{ game }}</p>
{% endfor %}
          {% for result in results %}
        <p>{{ result }}</p>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works, but the problem is, here is the values displayed on the webpage.

```
"{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': None}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'UNDER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'UNDER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'UNDER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'UNDER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'UNDER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': None}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'UNDER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'UNDER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'UNDER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'OVER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'UNDER'}

{'actual_over_under_result_field': 'UNDER'}"
```

I'm only looking for the "UNDER" or "OVER" value to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `values_list` with `flat=True`

```
results = PreviousLossesMlbV2.objects.values_list('actual_over_under_result_field', flat=True)
```